# How to display a warning at the beginning of a calculation?

Tags: android, button, message, wait

In Android Studio Java, one of my buttons launches a calculation which takes approximately 30 seconds on a mobile phone (on a Samsung S4 for instance). I would like to display a message as soon as the user has clicked on the button saying something like "I need to think a few seconds...", so that people don't think their phone has frozen. But in my code shown below the message is displayed only at the end of the calculations, so is useless. How to remedy this? Thanks

```
.........
else if (nbCoupsRestants == 7) {
                // on prend une photo du jeu avant le coup
                for (int i=1; i<33;i++){nombresBackOne[i] = nombres[i];}
                nbCoupsRestants--;
                tour = "A";
                backOneMoveUsed = false;
                Jeu.monMessage.append("I need to think a few seconds\n");
                //ne sert à rien car n'est affiché qu'après que tous les calculs sont finis!!!
                monMessage.append("B played\n");
                DistributionMoins7.BJoue();
            }
 .......
```

Comment: Are you doing your calculation on the UI Thread ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand your question? Here is what I do: I have developed a game (first on Eclipse, then on Android) in java, which works correctly. The Eclipse "plain vanilla" java version works on Windows and Linux PCs. The Android Studio version works on mobile phones. There is a User Interface with one screen and a few buttons and textfield areas. One of the buttons launches a long calculation (about 30 seconds), and I would like to warn the user when the button has just been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Start computation in background thread (for example, use AsyncTask)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this Async Task functionality.